# Make z-index child higher than parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've seen several posts like this and I haven't found anything specifically targeting the problem I am having (maybe I didn't search enough, forgive me for that!).

Anyway, I basically need my child div to position itself over the parent div. 
Here's the catch though, **the child has to be nested inside the parent div**, example:

```
<div id="parent">
 <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

My parent is basically a moving block (that you can move with arrow keys) and the child is basically an attribute to the parent and should move with it but over it as well.

Is this possible? 
I also want to do this without having to write a separate movement code for the child.

Comment: the child should lay on top of the parent by default, also moving the parent will move the child as well. Looks like the problem is in your actual code, so you should post it.

Comment: Unless you give the child an absolute position, I'm not sure how you could avoid this behavior. Can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this CSS to peg the child to be the full size of the parent (which will cover the parent background):

```
#parent {position: relative; height: 200px; width: 200px;}
#child {position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%;}
```

Working demo that shows you can move the parent and the child stays covering it: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/XGU4w/

---

Or, if you only have the one single child, then it's simply a matter of setting the child height and width to be `100%` and then setting a size on the parent.

```
#parent {height: 200px; width: 200px;}
#child {height: 100%; width: 100%;}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/s89a3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sNW8W/

You simply have to give the child element a higher z-index. The code from the previous answer would not work, providing no z-index. Remember: only elements that carry the position attribute can make use of the z-index property.

```
#parent {
    position: relative;
    background:red;
    height:100px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index:0;
 }
#child {
     position: absolute;
     top: -10px;
     left: 25px;
     background: green;
     height: 50px;
     width:   50px;
     z-index: 10;
 }
```

Comment: The child is already on top of the parent by default.  You don't need a `z-index` to force that.

Comment: Does this mean, that the 3rd child for example automatically has 3? I didn't know that. Thanks

Comment: A `z-index` affects the relative height of siblings.  Children are always on top of their parent and always relative to their parent container (so if their parent is above some other object, then all the children will be too).  The 3rd child doesn't get a z-index assigned (though it sort of acts like that).  The order is determined by parent z-order, then z-index setting vs. other siblings, then if no z-index by child order (last child is on top).

Comment: I agree, it's logic, but I've had some issues with this in the past. When you declare it specifically, you are save.